# PHP error on template export, after upgrading to 2.6

Tags: templates, php, error, upgrade, export

Getting the following when I try to export any template group...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Design::$api

Filename: cp/design.php

Line Number: 3516

Fatal error: Call to a member function instantiate() on a non-object in (mypath)/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/design.php on line 3516
```

I have disabled *all* third-party add-ons, as well as tried a clean install followed by a database import, and the problem persists. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19322) related to disabling custom fields in your channel entries tag pair. Give this solution a try and see if it resolves the problem. It should be fixed up in the next release.

Comment: That's a different bug to this one. I filed a new bug report on this one since it's verifiable with a fresh install and currently unreported. Here's the [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19331) Shame you can't read it easily, someone, maybe me didn't close his code tag.

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been posted now to the [bug 19331](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19331). Just a few lines to replace. Just tested it and it's working fine.